# VB.net Auto Newline After Copying

Tags: vb.net, string

First of all, I'm still new in VB.net and I had encountered one weird issue

I had created a tools that will split content from multilines textbox A into lines of string and add some characters and join them back and display in another multilines textbox B (A -> split content -> add character -> join -> display in B). The sample would be like this

Original Data from A:

```
This
is
a
test
data
```

Result Displayed in B:

```
Row 0 = This
Row 1 = is
Row 2 = a
Row 3 = test
Row 4 = data
```

Result COPIED from B:

```
Row 0 = This
Row 1 = 
is
Row 2 = 
a
Row 3 = 
test
Row 4 = 
data
```

The source code is

```
tempA = ""
tempB = ""

tempA = A.Text()
stringAry = tempA.Split(Environment.NewLine)
For iCounter As Integer = 0 To stringAry.Length - 1
tempB = tempB + "Row " + iCounter.ToString + " = " + stringAry(iCounter).ToString +     Environment.NewLine
Next
B.Text() = tempB
```

So may I know why the copied result will be different from result displayed and how could I solve this?

Comment: Where is the question???. I can see the sample and source code but what are you asking?

Comment: Sorry for the issue, the question I would like to ask is why the copied result will be different from result displayed and how could I solve this

Comment: In your source code there is only the passage where you take original data from A and display the result in B. What you mean by result COPIED from B? If I manually copy the content from B to notepad I obtain the same result/formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove any unwanted new line characters from the `stringAry(iCounter)` value.

```
tempA = ""
tempB = ""

tempA = A.Text()
stringAry = tempA.Split(Environment.NewLine)
For iCounter As Integer = 0 To stringAry.Length - 1
tempB = tempB + "Row " + iCounter.ToString + " = " + stringAry(iCounter).ToString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty) +     Environment.NewLine
Next
B.Text() = tempB
```

Comment: I had tried to replace any Environment.NewLine and vbCrLf from each of the array before joining as below

tempA = ""
tempB = ""

tempA = A.Text()
stringAry = tempA.Split(Environment.NewLine)
For iCounter As Integer = 0 To stringAry.Length - 1
sTemp = stringAry(iCounter).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
tempB = tempB + "Row " + iCounter.ToString + " = " + sTemp +     Environment.NewLine
Next
B.Text() = tempB

But seems likethe output is still the same